# How to Groupby in linq

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have a List  collection, that I bind to a ItemSource to a WPF DataGrid. In the collection I want to group by a column that could have the same value.

e.g.

ID 1, Name J, UID 0

ID 1, Name J, UID 1

So I would like to Group by ID so I want ID 1 and UID 0 on the top row and then UID 1 on a row below it. Like banding

I have tried this

```
         IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Customer>> groups = value.GroupBy(x => x.ID);
         IEnumerable<Customer> cust = groups.SelectMany(group => group);
         value = cust.ToList();
```

But the count in the List comes back as the same number. What am I doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by _count in the List comes back as the same number_? Do you expect to see number of groups or number of items in all groups?

Comment: I mean the groupby above should return only 1 because I am grouping by ID, but it would come back as 2

Comment: `groups.Count()` would return you 1 but `cust` concatenates all items from each group because you use `SelectMany` which effectively flattens all your groups to single list again.

Comment: So there is no way using the above that I can return the one item into the list?

Comment: You can use `Select` instead of `SelectMany` but the output will be each item being a group of `Customer`. Each `IGrouping<int, Customer>` is also `IEnumerable<Customer>`

Comment: Not to sure how I could use select as groups is a collection, so I cant do groups.Select(x => x.ID).. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Customer>> groups = value.GroupBy(x => new { x.ID, x.Name, x.UID});
IEnumerable<Customer> cust = groups.SelectMany(group => group);
value = cust.ToList();
```

> What am I doing wrong?

You don't make the grouping on the three columns you want, but only on one of them.

Comment: Yes I totally agree, my mistake, however the above won't work as The Igroup returns a Key, IEnumerable<IGrouping<int> so I cant use a property that isnt an INT. But your logic is correct thanks¬